# when the input field is not active no input should be accepted by input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

In this [codepen by thinhlam](https://codepen.io/thinhlam/pen/BowEPp), when input field is active then input is accepted, that's working fine. But when, some other input field is active then also input can be taken by the previously active input field.
As you can see in below image:

[image]

Although previously "single Text" field was active but then I switched to "Paragraph Text" block without clicking my cursor into input area, so "single Text" is still accepting input.

```js
(function() {
    var guid = 1;

    var app = angular.module('DragDropApp', ['ui.sortable']);

    app.controller('DragDropCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.dragElements = [{
            'Name': "Single Text",
            'Type': "text",
            'Settings': [{
                'Name': 'Field Label',
                'Value': 'Single Text',
                'Type': 'text'
            }, {
                'Name': 'Short Label',
                'Value': 'Single Text',
                'Type': 'text'
            }, {
                'Name': 'Internal Name',
                'Value': 'xSingle_Text',
                'Type': 'text'
            }, {
                'Name': 'Field Type',
                'Value': 'Single Text',
                'Type': 'string'
            }, {
                'Name': 'Single Line Text Options',
                'Value': '',
                'Type': 'label'
            }, {
                'Name': 'Max Input Length',
                'Value': '50',
                'Type': 'text'
            }, {
                'Name': 'Url Template',
                'Value': '',
                'Type': 'text'
            }, {
                'Name': 'Column Span',
                'Value': '1',
                'Type': 'dropdown',
                'PossibleValue': ['1', '2']
            }, {
                'Name': 'General Options',
                'Type': 'checkBoxZone',
                'Options': [{
                    'Name': 'Required',
                    'Value': false
                }, {
                    'Name': 'Show on list',
                    'Value': false
                }, {
                    'Name': 'Unique',
                    'Value': false
                }, {
                    'Name': 'Index',
                    'Value': false
                }]
            }

            ]
        }, {
            'Name': "Date",
            'Type': "date",
            'Settings': [{
                'Name': 'Field Label',
                'Value': 'Field Label',
                'Type': 'text'
            }, {
                'Name': 'Short Label',
                'Value': 'Short Label',
                'Type': 'text'
            }, {
                'Name': 'Internal Name',
                'Value': 'Internal Name',
                'Type': 'text'
            }, {
                'Name': 'Field Type',
                'Value': 'Date',
                'Type': 'string'
            }, {
                'Name': 'Display Type',
                'Value': '',
                'Type': 'radio',
                'PossibleValue': [
                    {
                        'Text' : 'DateTimeInstance',
                        'Checked' : true
                    },
                    {
                        'Text' : 'DateTimeLocal',
                        'Checked' : false
                    },
                    {
                        'Text' : 'DateLocal',
                        'Checked' : false
                    },
                    {
                        'Text' : 'Time',
                        'Checked' : false
                    },
                    ]
            }, {
                'Name': 'Column Span',
                'Value': '1',
                'Type': 'dropdown',
                'PossibleValue': ['1', '2']
            }, {
                'Name': 'General Options',
                'Type': 'checkBoxZone',
                'Options': [{
                    'Name': 'Required',
                    'Value': false
                }, {
                    'Name': 'Show on list',
                    'Value': false
                }, {
                    'Name': 'Unique',
                    'Value': false
                }, {
                    'Name': 'Index',
                    'Value': false
                }]
            }

            ]
        }, {
            'Name': "Singe Selection",
            "Type": "dropdown"
            }

            ]
        }, {
            'Name': "Pagaraph Text",
            "Type": "textarea"
            }, {
                'Name': 'Field Type',
                'Value': 'Paragraph Text',
                'Type': 'string'
            }, {
                'Name': 'Column Span',
                'Value': '1',
                'Type': 'dropdown',
                'PossibleValue': ['1', '2']
            }, {
                'Name': 'General Options',
                'Type': 'checkBoxZone',
                'Options': [{
                    'Name': 'Required',
                    'Value': false
                }, {
                    'Name': 'Enable Rich Text',
                    'Value': false
                }, {
                    'Name': 'Active',
                    'Value': true
                }, {
                    'Name': 'Hidden',
                    'Value': false
                }]
            }

            ]
        }];

        $scope.formFields = [];

        $scope.current_field = {};

        var createNewField = function() {
            return {
                'id': ++guid,
                'Name': '',
                'Settings': [],
                'Active': true,
                'ChangeFieldSetting': function(Value, SettingName) {
                    switch (SettingName) {
                        case 'Field Label':
                        case 'Short Label':
                        case 'Internal Name':
                            $scope.current_field.Name = Value;
                            $scope.current_field.Settings[0].Value = $scope.current_field.Name;
                            $scope.current_field.Settings[1].Value = $scope.current_field.Name;
                            $scope.current_field.Settings[2].Value = 'x' + $scope.current_field.Name.replace(/\s/g, '_');
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                },
                'GetFieldSetting': function(settingName) {
                    var result = {};
                    var settings = this.Settings;
                    $.each(settings, function(index, set) {
                        if (set.Name == settingName) {
                            result = set;
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                    if (!Object.keys(result).length) {
                        //Continue to search settings in the checkbox zone
                        $.each(settings[settings.length - 1].Options, function(index, set) {
                            if (set.Name == settingName) {
                                result = set;
                                return;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return result;

                }
            };
        }

        $scope.changeFieldName = function(Value) {
            $scope.current_field.Name = Value;
            $scope.current_field.Settings[0].Value = $scope.current_field.Name;
            $scope.current_field.Settings[1].Value = $scope.current_field.Name;
            $scope.current_field.Settings[2].Value = 'x' + $scope.current_field.Name.replace(/\s/g, '_');
        }

        $scope.removeElement = function(idx){
            if($scope.formFields[idx].Active) {
                $('#addFieldTab_lnk').tab('show');
                $scope.current_field = {};

            }
            $scope.formFields.splice(idx, 1);
        };

        $scope.addElement = function(ele, idx) {
            $scope.current_field.Active = false;

            $scope.current_field = createNewField();
            //Merge setting from template object
            angular.merge($scope.current_field, ele);

            if (typeof idx == 'undefined') {
                $scope.formFields.push($scope.current_field);
            } else {
                $scope.formFields.splice(idx, 0, $scope.current_field);
                $('#fieldSettingTab_lnk').tab('show');
            }

        };

        $scope.activeField = function(f) {
            $scope.current_field.Active = false;
            $scope.current_field = f;
            f.Active = true;
            $('#fieldSettingTab_lnk').tab('show');
        };

        $scope.formbuilderSortableOpts = {
            'ui-floating': true,

        };
    });

    app.directive('elementDraggable', ['$document', function($document) {
        return {
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                element.on('dragstart', function(event) {

                    event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('templateIdx', $(element).data('index'));
                });
            }
        };
    }]);

    app.directive('elementDrop', ['$document', function($document) {
        return {
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {

                element.on('dragover', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                });

                $('.drop').on('dragenter', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                })
                element.on('drop', function(event) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    var self = $(this);
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        var idx = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('templateIdx');
                        var insertIdx = self.data('index')
                        scope.addElement(scope.dragElements[idx], insertIdx);
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    }]);

})();

$(function() {
    // Code here
    var dh = $(document).height();
    $('#sidebar-tab-content').height(dh - 115);
    $('#main-content').height(dh - 10);
});
```

```css
body {
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: #75736f;
    overflow: hidden;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}


a {
    color: #75736f;
}

a:focus,
a:hover,
a:visited,
a:active,
a:link {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #75736f;
}

ul.neo-nav {
    border: 2px solid #75736f;
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-padding-start: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
    padding-start: 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

ul.neo-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.neo-nav li a {
    color: #75736f;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
}

ul.neo-nav li.active a {
    color: white;
}

ul.neo-nav li:not(:first-child) {
    border-left: 2px solid #75736f;
}

ul.neo-nav li.active {
    background-color: #75736f;
    color: white;
}

ul.neo-nav li a:hover,
ul.neo-nav li a:visited,
ul.neo-nav li a:active,
ul.neo-nav li a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#main-content {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#sideBar {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.tab-container {
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#addFieldTab {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#fieldSettingTab {
    padding: 20px;
}

#stdFields {}

#formBuilderContent {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}

.dragElement-wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.dragElement-wrapper .drag-element {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dragElement-wrapper .drag-element i {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

[draggable] {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    /* Required to make elements draggable in old WebKit */

    -khtml-user-drag: element;
    -webkit-user-drag: element;
}

#chkBoxZone {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.input-as-label {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.active-field {
    background-color: #f1fafc;
}

.form-group {
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.form-group i.remove-ico {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.pale {
    opacity: 50%;
}

.sortable-formbuilder,
.sortable-stdFields {
    padding-left: 0px;
    -moz-padding-start: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
    -khtml-padding-start: 0px;
    -o-padding-start: 0px;
    padding-start: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    min-height: 40px;
}

.drop-to-add {
    height: 40px;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] i.fa-plus-square-o {
    display: none;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] i.fa-minus-square-o {
    display: inline-block;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed i.fa-plus-square-o {
    display: inline-block;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed i.fa-minus-square-o {
    display: none;
}

.orange-txt {
    color: orange;
}
#sidebar-tab-content{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="DragDropApp">
<body ng-controller="DragDropCtrl">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" id="sideBar">
            <div class="tab-container text-center">
                <ul class="neo-nav clearfix" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#addFieldTab" id="addFieldTab_lnk" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Add a Field</a></li><!--

                    --><li role="presentation"><a href="#fieldSettingTab" id="fieldSettingTab_lnk" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Field Settings</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-content" id="sidebar-tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="addFieldTab">
                    <p>
                        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#stdFields">
                            <i class="fa fa-lg fa-plus-square-o"></i><i class="fa fa-lg fa-minus-square-o"></i> STANDARD FIELDS
                        </a>
                    </p>

                    <div class="collapse in" id="stdFields">
                        <ul  ng-model="dragElements" class="sortable-stdFields">
                            <li draggable="true" class="dragElement-wrapper" ng-repeat="ele in dragElements" element-draggable data-index="{{$index}}">
                                <div class="drag-element" ng-click="addElement(ele)" >
                                    <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> {{ele.Name}}
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>

                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="fieldSettingTab">

                    <div ng-repeat="set in current_field.Settings" ng-switch on="set.Type">
                        <div >

                            <div class="form-group " ng-switch-when="text">
                                <label for="{{set.Name.replace(' ','_')}}">{{set.Name}}</label>
                                <input ng-change="current_field.ChangeFieldSetting(set.Value, set.Name)" type="text" ng-model="set.Value"  class="form-control" id="{{set.Name.replace(' ','_')}}" value="{{set.Value}}" placeholder="{{set.Name}}">
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group" ng-switch-when="string">
                                <label >{{set.Name}}</label>
                                <br>
                                <span >{{set.Value}}</span>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group" ng-switch-when="label">
                                <label class="pale">{{set.Name}}</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group " ng-switch-when="dropdown" >
                                <label >{{set.Name}}</label>
                                <select class="form-control" ng-model="set.Value" >
                                    <option ng-repeat="op in set.PossibleValue">{{op}}</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group" ng-switch-when="radio">
                                <div ng-repeat="val in set.PossibleValue" class="radio">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios"  value="{{val.Checked}}" ng-checked="val.Checked">
                                        {{val.Text}}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group" ng-switch-when="dropdown_increment">
                                <label class="control-label">
                                    Choices
                                </label>
                                <div ng-repeat="val in set.PossibleValue" class="radio" class="form-control">
                                    <i class="fa fa-sort fa-lg">

                                    </i>
                                    &nbsp;
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-lg">

                                    </i>
                                    <input type="text"  value="val.Text" ng-model="val.Text">
                                </div>

                            </div>



                            <div ng-switch-when="checkBoxZone">
                                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#chkBoxZone">
                                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-plus-square-o"></i><i class="fa fa-lg fa-minus-square-o"></i> {{set.Name}}
                                </a>
                                <div class="collapse in" id="chkBoxZone">
                                    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="op in set.Options">
                                        <label class="checkbox-inline" >
                                            <input type="checkbox" value="{{op.Value}}" ng-model="op.Value"> {{op.Name}}
                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p ng-switch-default>
                                Unknown
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 text-center" id="main-content">
            <ul class="neo-nav" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#addFieldTab" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Form Builder</a></li><!--
                 --><li role="presentation"><a href="#" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Entity & Field Permission</a></li><!--
                 --><li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Detail Builder</a></li><!--
                 --><li role="presentation"><a href="#" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Workflows</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active text-left" id="formBuilderContent">

                    <p>
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i>
                        <span class="lead">Employee</span>
                    </p>

                    <div class="container-fluid" id="dropZone">
                        <ul class="row sortable-formbuilder" element-drop  ui-sortable="formbuilderSortableOpts" ng-model="formFields" id="sortable-formbuilder-ul">
                            <li  ng-repeat="field in formFields" element-drop data-index="{{$index}}" ng-switch on="field.Type" ng-class="field.GetFieldSetting('Column Span').Value == 1 ? 'col-md-6 sortable-field' : 'col-md-12 sortable-field' " ng-click="activeField(field)" data-index="{{$index}}">

                                <div class="form-group "  ng-switch-when="text" ng-class="field.Active ? 'active-field' : '' " >

                                    <input type="text" class="input-as-label" ng-model="field.Name" value="{{field.Name + (field.GetFieldSetting('Required') ? '*': '')}}" ng-change="field.ChangeFieldSetting(field.Name,'Field Label')"/>
                                    <span ng-if="field.GetFieldSetting('Required').Value" class="orange-txt">*</span>

                                    <!--<label ng-if="!field.Active" for="{{field.Name.replace(' ','_') + field.id}}">{{field.Name}}<span ng-if="field.GetFieldSetting('Required')">*</span></label> -->

                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{field.Name.replace(' ','_') + field.id}}" value="{{field.Value}}" placeholder="{{field.Name}}">
                                    <i class ="fa fa-lg fa-minus-square-o remove-ico" ng-click="removeElement($index)" ng-if="field.Active"></i>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group k" ng-switch-when="date" ng-class="field.Active ? 'active-field' : '' ">
                                    <input type="text" class="input-as-label" ng-model="field.Name" value="{{field.Name + (field.GetFieldSetting('Required').Value ? '*': '')}}" ng-change="field.ChangeFieldSetting(field.Name,'Field Label')"/>
                                    <span ng-if="field.GetFieldSetting('Required').Value" class="orange-txt">*</span>
                                    <div class="has-feedback">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="{{field.Name}}">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar form-control-feedback custom-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        <span id="inputSuccess2Status" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
                                    </div>

                                    <i class ="fa fa-lg fa-minus-square-o remove-ico" ng-if="field.Active"  ng-click="removeElement($index)"></i>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group " ng-switch-when="dropdown" ng-class="field.Active ? 'active-field' : '' ">
                                    <input type="text" class="input-as-label" ng-model="field.Name" value="{{field.Name + (field.GetFieldSetting('Required').Value ? '*': '')}}" ng-change="field.ChangeFieldSetting(field.Name,'Field Label')"/>
                                    <span ng-if="field.GetFieldSetting('Required').Value" class="orange-txt">*</span>
                                    <select class="form-control" >
                                        <option ng-repeat="val in field.GetFieldSetting('Choice').PossibleValue">
                                            {{val.Text}}
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                    <i class ="fa fa-lg fa-minus-square-o remove-ico" ng-if="field.Active"  ng-click="removeElement($index)"></i>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group " ng-switch-when="textarea" ng-class="field.Active ? 'active-field' : '' ">
                                    <input type="text" class="input-as-label" ng-model="field.Name" value="{{field.Name + (field.GetFieldSetting('Required').Value ? '*': '')}}" ng-change="field.ChangeFieldSetting(field.Name,'Field Label')"/>
                                    <span ng-if="field.GetFieldSetting('Required').Value" class="orange-txt">*</span>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="{{field.Name.replace(' ','_')  + field.id}}" rows="4"></textarea>
                                    <i class ="fa fa-lg fa-minus-square-o remove-ico" ng-if="field.Active"  ng-click="removeElement($index)"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div ng-switch-default>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="drop-to-add col-md-12" element-drop>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this. Thanks

Comment: my problem is, if there are more than one fields in the main-content, then if i switch between them without clicking on input area, then previously active field still accepts the input, and in recently activated field, first i have to click on the input area to completely bring the focus on new field.